# C++ check for property value in unordered_set instead of whole object

Tags: c++, sorting, lookup, unique-ptr, unordered-set

I have an `std::unordered_set` of `std::unique_ptr`. The pointers point at nodes which contain a `std::array<2, int>`, which represent a 2d position. The insertion in the set in specified by  the code below

```
struct VectorHash {
    size_t operator()(const std::unique_ptr<Node>& ptr) const {
        std::hash<int> hasher;
        size_t seed = 0;
        for (int i : ptr->position) {
            seed ^= hasher(i) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
        }
        return seed;
    }
};
```

Say i have a position and i want to check if there are any `std::unique_ptr`s that have the same position, will have to do i brute force search or can i somehow use the hashing function to do a lookup? I thought this might be possible since the position kind off becomes the key, or am I wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: How can you have an unordered set with a hasher that do not work with keys? You say that your keys are unique pointers, but your hasher does not accept unique pointers as arguments. Also note that you might want to use a custom equality predicate.

Comment: If `PositionHash` is assigned as the `unordered_set`'s hash algorithm, then [`std::unordered_set::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) should work fine for finding existing elements. However, the hash needs to take the set's `Key` type, so if you have a `Key` type that is `unique_ptr` then the input to the hash needs to be `unique_ptr`, not the type the `unique_ptr` points at. The hasher can dereference the `unique_ptr` to hash its content.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Daniel Langr

Comment: @RemyLebeau, but the unordered_set has to store the a unique hash somewhere. Is there som function or technique that would let me hash a position and se if its already exists? Like this closed_set.find(position) != closed_vect.end() where position is of type std::array<int, 2>

Comment: @HenrikMelfaldKittang "*but the unordered_set has to store the a unique hash somewhere*" - no, it doesn't.  That is not how it uses hashes. You simply search for the desired `Key` value, and it will hash it right then and there and then compare that to the hashes of the existing elements. The hashes themselves are not stored anywhere. If that doesn't work for you, then consider using `std::find_if()` instead.